# wpf csharp convert numerickeyup value to int

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I have a window form that has multiple numerickeyup boxes, i will for the most part use 1's and 0's,.
when the fields are being set, its fine,. the problem is when i send the changes back to the webservice, when i compile the code it gives me an error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

here is the code that after adding it causes this error, also FYI this code is so i can send into the web service new values for the roles

```
          private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Roledata.UpdateRole(Roleui.Username,Roleui.Password,
            Role.ID = numericUpDown1ID.Value,
        Role.RoleName = txtRoleName.Text,
        Role.Weather = numericUpDown1Weather.Value,
        Role.National = numericUpDown1National.Value,
        Role.International = numericUpDown1International.Value,
        Role.Local = numericUpDown1Local.Value,
        Role.SendConfirm = numericUpDown1SendConfirm.Value);
        Close();

    }
```

Comment: You need to Convert the decimal value to an integer if you want to use the numericUpDown control.

Comment: @Gabe - The author clearly means the NumericUpdown control.  You can tell based on the fact he has 6 of them.

Comment: @Ramhound: If you know what the OP means, please suggest an edit so that the question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The .Value return is a decimal as the error is stating and it is trying to convince that it will not do an imlicit conversion from decimal to int which I assume your values on the Role object are.  You would be best to do a int.Parse(...) on your numericUpDown objects or better yet an int.TryParse(...) and check the return to see if it could accurately parse the decimal value into an int which it should be able to.

Further reading on .Value from [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx)

Comment: would you be able to give me more details how exactly to do it ? im sorry i am new to this

Comment: @IzzyG - You need to cast the value, we have provided you EVERYTHING you need to solve the problem, it requires some work on your end.

Answer (score 0):

... or you can use cast operation =)

like this:

```
decimal q;
int w = (int)q;
```

Comment: so what do i do? how do i fix my problem and convert them to int?

Comment: putting the (int) helped, i will answer this as soon as i see no other issues

Comment: @IzzyG - This is your code.  You asked the reason your getting this error we told you.  We told you exactly how to fix it, use your programming knowlege to fix it, or at the very least accept some of your previous qustion's answers.

Comment: if `Role.ID` is int value and `numericUpDown1ID.Value` is decimal value you have to change this line to: `Role.ID = (int)numericUpDown1ID.Value`